# Property 'percentage' does not exist on type 'Point | Series'

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

```
legend:{
      enabled:true,
      labelFormatter: function () {
        return this.name+':' +this.y+'('+this.percentage.toFixed(1) +'%)';
      }
},
```

In angular code for highcharts piechart, in legend i am getting below error

```
1.Property 'y' does not exist on type 'Point | Series'
2.Property 'percentage' does not exist on type 'Point | Series'
```

[image]
How to resolve these issues

Comment: Where are `y` and `percentage` declared? Can you post relevant code? Adding a snapshot doesn't help. Try creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function instead:

```
legend:{
      enabled:true,
      labelFormatter: () => {
        return this.name+':' +this.y+'('+this.percentage.toFixed(1) +'%)';
      }
},
```

Comment: Usage of `function` seems correct here. In the arrow function, `this` will refer to the class instance instead.

Comment: Maybe its a typings issue.

Comment: how to avoid typing issues, using arrow function not resolved the problem

Comment: As @31piy mentioned above, could you please post more details?

Comment: I am adding extra text to legend with dynamic variable values , in browser legends are showing added dynamic text properly ,but in vs code the above error occurs

Comment: Does this works? return this.name+':' +this['y']+'('+this['percentage'].toFixed(1) +'%)';

Comment: Yes  return this.name+':' +this['y']+'('+this['percentage'].toFixed(1) +'%)'; is working fine. Thank you